# Does the notion “weak convergence” coincide with that using in functional analysis?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let $\mu_k$ be a sequence of probability (Borel) measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. We say, $\mu_k$ converges to a probability measure $\mu$ **weakly** if $\int gd\mu_k \to \int gd\mu$ for every continuous bounded real function $g$.

Let $M_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$. What would be the topology on $M_b(\mathbb{R}^n)$ so that a sequence in this spaces converges with respect to the topology **if and only if** it converges weakly with respect to the above definition?

And, is this topology the **weak** topology of some space in the sense of functional analysis?

The only natural topology I know on $M_b(\mathbb{R^n})$ is that induced by the total variation, but I think this topology is not the answer for my question.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any probability measure $\mu$ you can define the linear continuos operator   in $A_\mu\in (L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(R^n))^*$ (that is the dual space of the continuos bounded, that are oviously function Borel measurable) in this way:

$A_\mu: L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{R}$
such that for every $g\in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) $

$A_\mu(g)=\int gd\mu$

Now you can consider the weak$^* $Topology on $(L ^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) )^*$ for which the succession $\{A_{\mu_k}\}_k\to A_\mu$ if and only if for any $g\in L ^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) $ you have that $j(g)(A_{\mu_k})\to j(g)(A_{\mu})$ (where $j$ is the canonical injection) that means :

for every $g\in L ^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) $

$\int gd\mu_k\to \int gd\mu$

So you can interpretate the definition of the convergence of probability measure as the converge in the weak$^* $ Topology of the space $(L ^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap C^0(\mathbb{R}^n) )^*$

Comment: First: don't you need bounded Borel functions? Second: isn't the convergence in this topology stronger (you have to test not only against bounded continuous function, but also against bounded Borel functions) than the weak convergence of probability measure?

Comment: Ooops you have reason, I read badly sorry. Do you think that if I consider the dual of the intersection between L^\infty and C_0 i resolve this problem?

Comment: If with $C_0$ you denote the space of continuous functions, I think that $L^\infty\cap C_0$ works well.

Comment: I was referring to the intersection  of those two spaces

Comment: I suggest to use the more standard notation $C^0$ instead $C_0$: it is common to use the notation $C_0$ for continuous functions that vanish at $\infty$

Comment: Thanks you, now I change it

Answer (score 2):

This is a long comment / supplement to Frederico's answer, and gives a relatively explicit description of the dual. The main result I will use is the following:

> **Theorem** (Riesz representation theorem): Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $C(X)$ be the space of continuous functions on $X$ and $M(X)$ be the space of regular signed Borel measures on $X.$ Then the map,
>   $$ \varphi : M(X) \longrightarrow C(X)^* $$
>   defined by,
>   $$\varphi(\mu)(f) = \int_X f \,\mathrm{d}\mu$$
>   is an isometric isomorphism.

The case $X = \mathbb R^n$ is a bit more subtle; the identification we get is,
$$ C_b(\mathbb R^n)^* \cong M(\beta\, \mathbb R^n),$$
where $C_b(\mathbb R^n)$ is the space of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R^n,$ and $\beta\, \mathbb R^n$ is the Stone–Čech compactification of $\mathbb R^n.$ This follows from the universal property, which implies that $C(\beta\,\mathbb R^n) \cong C_b(\mathbb R^n).$ Tracing through the isomorphisms, we get the pairing is,
$$ \langle f, \mu \rangle = \int_{\beta\, \mathbb R^n} \tilde f \,\mathrm{d}\mu,$$
where $f \in C_b(\mathbb R^n),$ $\mu \in M(\beta\,\mathbb R^n)$ and $\tilde f$ is the unique continuous extension of $f$ to $\beta\, \mathbb R^n.$

Note that we can easily embed $M_b(\mathbb R^n)$ into $C_b(X)^*,$ but it's not obvious how a probability measure on $\mathbb R^n$ extends to a signed measure on $\beta\,\mathbb R^n.$ [See the edit below.]

Note: An important point is that $M_b(\mathbb R^n)$ only identifies with a subspace of $C_b(X)^*,$ so it may be the case that a weakly Cauchy sequence does not converge to any probability measure. I'm not actually sure whether this statement is true or false however.

Additional note: The space of signed (regular) Borel measures on $\mathbb R^n$ can be identified with $C_0(\mathbb R^n)$; the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity. This essentially follows by taking the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^n.$

---

Edit: Actually, there is a natural way to embed $M_b(\mathbb R^n)$ into $M(\beta\,\mathbb R^n);$ you extend the measure by saying $\beta\,\mathbb R^n \setminus \mathbb R^n$ is a null set. More precisely, for $\mu \in M_b(\mathbb R^n),$ we define $\tilde \mu \in M(\beta\,\mathbb R^n)$ by,
$$ \tilde \mu(A) = \mu(A \cap \mathbb R^n)$$
for any $A \subset \beta\,\mathbb R^n$ Borel measurable. Regularity of $\tilde \mu$ follows by regularity of $\mu$ (namely inner approximation by compact subsets), and $\tilde \mu$ coincides with $\mu$ with respect to the identifications we are making.

Comment: Interesting, thanks you for your answer